# How to get the cell value by using the row and column positions using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, indexing

I have created a html table.Now using the  row index and column index, I should get the cell value.
how to do it
Html:

```
<table border="2" width="200">
<tr>
<td></td>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>3</td>
<td>5</td>
<td>5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2</td>
<td>4</td>
<td>6</td>
<td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>3</td>
<td>5</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>4</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

jQuery:

```
var a=2;//row index
var b=3;//column index
var c=$("#tab").find('tr:eq(a)').find('td:eq(b)');
alert(c);
```

And I want to get the cell value using the index.
But this code is not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to concatenate the variables properly,

```
var a=2;//row index
var b=3;//column index
var c=$("#tab").find('tr:eq('+ a + ')').find('td:eq(' + b + ')');
alert(c.text());
```

Also you have to use `.text()` to extract the text content of the particular element.

Your code can also be written as,

```
var a=2;
var b=3;
var c= $("#tab tr:eq(" + a + ") td:eq(" + b + ")").text();
alert(c);
```

Comment: @Preethi 4 numbers? Are they row index or column index? Can you give a sample data?

Comment: Thanks!! But if i have an array like var a=[1,2,3,4] then how will find the cell value separately for 1st pair and 2nd pair

Comment: @Preethi You can do it like this, `var pairValue=[]; for(var i=0;i<a.length;i+=2){ pairValue.push($("#tab tr:eq(" + a[i] + ") td:eq(" + a[i+1] + ")").text()) }`

Comment: No.How do you display it? Like cell value of 1st pair is found followed by the 2nd pair value.

Comment: @Preethi pairValue is an array which will contain the values that we need. We can display it in any manner. Example: `console.log(pairValue)`

Comment: @Preethi https://jsfiddle.net/o2a3k402/2/ Mam, That is not working because we have only four columns there but we are searching for the fifth one by using the index four. That is why it is displaying `""` for the second pair.

Comment: Yeah Its working!! :) But then why do use console.log?

Comment: @Preethi Glad to help! Can we be friends at facebook? :)

Comment: @Jai Hehe.. :) :D Don't tell anyone. :)

Answer (score 1):

change to this with `.eq()` instead:

```
var c=$("#tab").find('tr').eq(a).find('td').eq(b).text();
console.log(c); // 2
```